# C# Datagridview using winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to delete a record from a `DataGridView`, when a record is selected.
 I get this exception error when I use the code below,

```
string conStrings = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ImpiDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
string sql = "Select * from tblImpi";
con = new SqlConnection(conStrings);
con.Open();
dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
//ImpiDbDataSet impds = new ImpiDbDataSet();
ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommandBuilder cmdb = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "tblImpi");
BindingSource bndS = new BindingSource();
bndS.DataSource = ds.Tables["tblImpi"];
impdg.DataSource = bndS;
```

delete button

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (MessageBox.Show("I you sure you want to delete this record?","Delete",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)==DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        impdg.Rows.RemoveAt(impdg.SelectedRows[0].Index);
        dataAdapter.Update(ds,"tblImpi");
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is.....?

Comment: put try...catch block inside btnDelete_Click.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to delete a record but removing it from the Grid does not remove it from the table.

Don't use the DataGridView directly to interact with your datasource but do it this way.

```
var table = ds.Tables["tblImpi"];
var row = impdg.SelectedRows[0];
var item = (DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem;
item.Delete();

// I am not 100% sure that row.DataBoundItem returns a DataRowView,
// if it returns a DataRow you can use
table.Rows.Remove(item); 
// instead of item.Delete();
```

Comment: Atleast I have manage to solve this problem from my code thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here is answer for the question.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("I you sure you want to delete this record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    impdg.Rows.RemoveAt(impdg.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                    dataAdapter.Update(dt1);



                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```